# input type file no returned value

Tags: javascript, php, html, input

Good day to all,

I'm trying to get the name/location/size of the file being uploaded. But It seems It won't display anything every time I looked in the console. But I followed everything here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

index.php

```
<form id="formAction" method="POST" action="add_item.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <input id="loc" type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

javascript

```
$("form#formAction").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "add_item.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Some fields are empty.');
            }
        });
    });
```

add_item.php

```
// fetching data
echo $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

What seems to be lacking? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two problems there:

First, you missed `enctype` attribute on your form. This is required for plain form submissions (without ajax):

```
<form id="formAction" method="POST" action="add_item.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Second, [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)'s native `$.ajax` doesn't support file uploads, but you can manage that using plugins, such as http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload.

Comment: Thanks. This should be the one I'm looking for.